# Another display format of com.google.protobuf.Timestamp in json

Tags: java, spring, jackson

there is a question about jackson
In version 2.12.6 fields with the type com.google.protobuf.Timestamp now looks like a number in json, although in version 2.11.3 they looked like an object with the fields "nano", "epochSecond"

For example:
before

```
"date": {
  "nano": 0,
  "epochSecond": 100000
}
```

now

```
"date": 100000
```

Proto file

```
 syntax = "proto3";

 import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

 message TopupInfo {
     google.protobuf.Timestamp TopupDate = 3;
 }
```

Sample test

```
package ru.home;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;

import ru.home.proto.TopupInfo;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class SampleTest {

    public static final int TOPUP_DATE = 100_000_000;

    private JacksonTester<TopupInfo> json;

    @BeforeEach
    public void makeATestObject() {
        var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, objectMapper);
    }

    @NotNull
    private TopupInfo makeTopupInfo() {

        var topupInfo = TopupInfo.newBuilder()
                 .setTopupDate(
                   com.google.protobuf.Timestamp.newBuilder()
                                                .setSeconds(millis / 1000)
                                                .setNanos((int) ((millis % 1000) * 1000000))
                                                .build());

        return topupInfo.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkFormat() throws IOException {
        assertThat(json.write(makeTopupInfo()))
                .extracting("topupDate")
                .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("epochSecond", TOPUP_DATE / 1000);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to configure it so that it is like in version 2.11.3?

I tried to adjust different settings, but nothing helped

Comment: can you share a small reproducer ?

Comment: Added an example. This example worked on spring 2.11.3. In spring 2.12.6, you need to add ObjectMapper.registerModule(new Java TimeModule()); but the test will not pass, because the hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue condition will not work